# How to use Ctrl-Mouse in ubuntu

Tags: shortcut, linux

I use ubuntu16.04 for blender-2.79b. I have problems where I cannot use the Ctrl in combination with the Mouse action.
Examples are:

- Ctrl-Scroll (scroll value)
- Ctrl-Drag-LMB (cut node connections)

Ctrl-Keyboard, e.g. Ctrl-Z, works fine.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solved, in a kind of sad way.

The cause was that I had the [mouse locator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986688/easy-way-to-quickly-locate-the-mouse-pointer) on. This over took the keyboard input of my Ctrl key.